Как узнать какой каталог к какому физ.устройству относится?
Возникла проблема.
Имею операционную систему Linux, а точнее дистрибутив Fedora.
ОС установлена на SSD, при этом часть места также выделена (предположительно, всякие фото/видео/прочие файлы) на HDD.
Как мне узнать, какой каталог физически относится к SSD, а какой к HDD?

findmnt -T <path> напечатает информацию о точке монтирования, устройстве и опциях монтирования для каталога <path>

можно попробовать такое сделать с помощью сочетание lsblk и findmnt утилит,
как вариант:
$ DIR=$HOME/Desktop; lsblk -dno TRAN,MODEL /dev/$(lsblk -no PKNAME $(findmnt --df -no SOURCE --target $DIR))
nvme   Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB

